# How to load third party script and initialise class in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Working Implementation:**

The following implementation in HTML file works. (Instructions from third party library)

```
<script src="https://cdn.somethirdpartyfile.js"></script>
<script>
  const client = new myThirdParyClass({
     param1: "test",
     param2: "test"
  });
</script>
```

**Problem:** [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-fast-ten4h-ten4h)

I am using the below code to add a 3rd party library to my react code base.

**index.html:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.somethirdpartyfile.js"></script>
```

**Component Code**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = function () {
      const client = new myThirdParyClass({
        param1: "test",
        param2: "test"
      });
    };

    // clean ups
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);
```

But my react code throws an error saying `myThirdParyClass` is not defined. How can I initialize the third-party class in my React component?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example in a sandbox [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Added sandbox link

Comment: Where is the CDN in index.html?

Comment: right after favicon. just added.

Comment: You realize that React is Javascript, right? What's the need for creating a script element?

Comment: And Persona is not a class, it's an object, did you read the docs?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the script code, you just don't use the library correctly, check it by `console.log(Persona)`. You don't need to initialize another `script` tag, those snippets are not equivalent.

Comment: @DennisVash Persona object has Client in it which I am trying to invoke as `const client = new Persona.Client({...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another `script` tag for it, just use the `Persona` object.

Of course, you will get `Persona un-def` because it loaded via script and not defined in the scope of the current module.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const client = new Persona.Client({
  templateId: "tmpl_FLYT5sonEPaDPmgGSSf8j1eD",
  environment: "sandbox",
  onComplete: (inquiryId) => {
    console.log(`Sending finished inquiry ${inquiryId} to backend`);
  }
});

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    client.open();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-fast-ten4h-forked-ryxg0?file=/src/App.js:60-522

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is create another component that returns the script. you want to do this dynamically because 3d party scripts change. essentially, as the article below says, load the script in the  of your react page only when you need it.

Here what i found from a quick google search.

https://medium.com/better-programming/loading-third-party-scripts-dynamically-in-reactjs-458c41a7013d

Answer (score 1):

can you try to add the *src* and add the *script tag* to the body in your component like this ?

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'https://cdn.somethirdpartyfile.js'; // new line
script.onload = function () {
   const client = new myThirdParyClass({
    param1: "test",
    param2: "test"
    });
  };
document.body.appendChild(script); // new line
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this too. But it still throws error: myThirdParyClass is not defined

Comment: isn't it that you want ? https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-fast-ten4h-forked-4cwxg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Turns out. It's the ESLint that wasn't allowing me to compile.